# How to remove Windows 8.1 and install Windows 7 without harming Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

I am currently running Windows 8.1 alongside Ubuntu 14.10. I want to remove Windows 8.1 and replace it with Windows 7 without harming my Ubuntu.
So that my final result should be, Dual boot running Ubuntu 14.10 with Windows 7.

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this is to go ahead and install Windows 7 and then use the Ubuntu disk to fix the dual boot.  You *can* set up windows 7 to be the boot manager, but I found it easier to just let Ubuntu handle it.

Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Yes, in detail will be kind. If I am installing Windows 7, then which partition to delete/format, so that it wont effect Ubuntu?

Comment: @ItsmePawan - The partition that contains Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound After formatting/deleting my Windows 8.1 partition, what will be my next step to integrate with Ubuntu? Ubuntu must know right, that end user is replacing Windows 8.1 to 7. What to do for that?

Comment: Right after you install Windows 7 you fix Grub, same as always there are hundreds of tutorials on a dual booting

Comment: Sorry for late response.  I wouldn't worry about messing things up as you are just updating the boot loader.  It won't delete partitions.  This looks pretty straight forward.  http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-restore-grub-2-after-reinstalling-windows-xpvistawin7